# jquery: fire href but add #hash to it?

Tags: jquery, hash, click, addition

```
/*Forum maintain scrollposition*/
$('#wpf-wrapper a').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + "#wpf-wrapper");
    });
});
```

I want all my links it his #wpf-wrapper section to be fired normal but get called with a #wpf-wrapper hash at the end?

Right now, when I click a link the link doesn't get fired anymore!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this will help.

```
$('#wpf-wrapper a').live('click',function() {       
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + "#wpf-wrapper");        
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you, that did the trick! don't know why, but the the live() handler makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - it rewrites the links as the page loads rather than on click:

```
$(function() {
    $('#wpf-wrapper a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + "#wpf-wrapper");
    });
});
```

Comment: I've already tried that, doesn't make a difference! The link doesn't get fired once I add the hash!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do a simple redirect

```
$('#wpf-wrapper a').live('click',function() {       
    window.location = $(this).attr('href') + "#wpf-wrapper";        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this `onclick`

```
$('#wpf-wrapper a').each(function() {
    this.href = this.href + '#wpf-wrapper';
});
```